# How to implement websockets in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, websocket

I want to create an AngularJS site that updates its information via websockets from the server.  The server will emit a new chunk of information every second.

This is the code I have:

```
myApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
  var connection = new WebSocket("ws:localhost:4080/", ['soap', 'xmpp']);
  $scope.value= "null";
  connection.onopen = function () {
    connection.onmessage = function (e) {
      $scope.value = e.data;
    };
  };
};
```

Comment: So what is the question? What is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the `$scope.value = e.data;` call into `$scope.$apply` function to propagate the data into view.

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
    $scope.value = e.data;
});
```